# How can I get track of external hits on android app debugger

Tags: android, azure

I am in a situation where I need to track the external API hits from my application in android.

Is there any way when I attach debugger to the app and then can get details of external API hits like complete request data: request header
and request body

PS: I am using azure sdk and it is hitting some API's. need to track their request data. So I can not put a log there (please dont suggest to insert log.e etc) as it is a 3rd party application.

Kindly give some suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code regarding the same

Comment: there is no code. I am asking a way. consider any 3rd party sdk which hit external requests internally. how do we track of those requests

Comment: if you getting a request payload from the 3rd party that means it is working fine which means it is hitting the external request as accepted. SO just use a variable and increment it each time

Comment: or if you have the sdk..Cant you modify it according to your wish? Just asking never tried that